# D3.js - Updating Bar Chart Data with buttons

Tags: javascript, d3.js

So I've been trying to get my d3.js bar chart to transition to different values when a button is pressed. Though, at the moment some elements seem to be adding, but extremely wide and all over the place, as well as the previous elements not being removed.

This is my code:

```
function updateData(time) {

timeValue = time;


// Get the data again
d3.tsv(timeValue + ".tsv", function(error, data) {
  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);
// Scale the range of the data again 
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.letter; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]); 

//Selecting Data
var bars = svg.selectAll("rect")
         .data(data);


//Removing
bars.exit().remove("rect");

//Changes
bars.enter().append('rect')
.attr("class", "bar")
bars.attr('x', function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
.attr('width', x.rangeBand())
.attr('y', function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
.attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.frequency); }); 
 //var svg = d3.select("div.innerScreen2").transition();        
});
```

Now I've looked at similar questions asked and tried to apply the solutions, but nothing seems to get removed or change :/ Maybe I have code in the wrong place? Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: You don't need to pass any value to `.remove` because it doesn't take any arguments yet. See https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/selection/remove.js

Comment: Also, where are your `range` definitions and why are you setting domains twice?

Comment: I have defined the range outside of this function, when I create the first display of the bar chart. The 2 domains was an accident, though I don't think it should have effected anything.

Comment: OK WOW nevermind, removing the double up of the domains fixed it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems to solve in your question. The first issue is related to the update pattern that some elements are added and some not. Do you have an unique identifier in your data set? If yes, you can use a function within the update process:

```
// Join new data with old elements, if any.
var text = svg.selectAll("text")
      .data(data, function(d) { return d.id; });
```

Source:http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808234

The second issue is related to your x/y positions and may depend on your underlying data. An data excerpt or debugging information are required to solve this issue.

Comment: My data is very basic and has 2 properties:
letter frequency
America .06967
Guyana .08492
Bolivia .01782
Mexico .03253
Venezuala .22702
Columbia .08288
Brazil .04015
Peru .08094
Ecuador .01966

I wanted to be able to load in another tsv file with the same countries, but different values

Comment: Thanks for the data excerpt and Oleg already solved the second issue to declare unique domains for the x/y positions.